# How to fix incompatibility between kapt, Java's and Kotlin's versions, using Dagger?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I have one problem in my Android project. I discovered this error:

compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

How to fix it?

I added this dependencies in build.gradle(:app) and added plugin `id 'kotlin-kapt'`:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.41'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.41'
implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

and tried to change Java's and Kotlin's version to 17.

But my project is crashed again. How can I change the version of kapt to be compatible with Java and Kotlin 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

Check Java and Kotlin versions:
In the build.gradle(:app) file, make sure the Java and Kotlin versions are compatible. To use Kotlin 1.5.0, for example, you can set the kotlin_version property at the top of the build.gradle file like this:

```
ext {
kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
```

}

Then make sure the Java version is also set correctly. For example:

```
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

}

Check versions of Dagger dependencies:
In the build.gradle(:app) file, make sure the Dagger dependencies are using the same version of Kotlin. In your case, you've already added the correct Dagger dependency and the kotlin-kapt plugin, which is great. Just make sure the versions line up. Make sure the dagger-compiler version matches the dagger version.

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.41'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.41'
```

Also make sure the javax.inject is using the correct version, if necessary.

Sync the project:
After making the above changes, sync the project in Android Studio to ensure that all changes are applied correctly.

If you're still having issues after these steps, check to see if other dependencies or plugins in your project are causing conflicts with your Kotlin and Java versions. Make sure all dependencies are up to date and compatible with the versions you are using.

Comment: You may want to double-check the formatting on this post, including line breaks and code blocks

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it didin't help. I also tried to do this: ```tasks.withType(type = KaptGenerateStubsTask::class) {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()

}``` after android block

Comment: I was mistaken, I wanted to write JavaVersion_1_8, and it didn't help too